# GDB not found in OS Catalina

Tags: c++, gdb, macos-catalina

I had GDB 8 installed in my Mac OS Catalina but when trying to upgrade it to 9 using Homebrew I removed everything. Now I obtain this:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:bin hectoresteban$ brew install gdb
Warning: gdb 9.1_1 is already installed, it's just not linked
You can use `brew link gdb` to link this version.
MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:bin hectoresteban$ gdb -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/gdb: No such file or directory
MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:bin hectoresteban$ brew link gdb
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/9.1_1... 
Error: Could not symlink include/gdb/jit-reader.h
Target /usr/local/include/gdb/jit-reader.h
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/gdb/jit-reader.h'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite gdb

To list all files that would be deleted:


brew link --overwrite --dry-run gdb
MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:include hectoresteban$ brew link --overwrite gdb

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gdb/9.1_1... 
Error: Could not symlink include/gdb/jit-reader.h
/usr/local/include/gdb is not writable.
(tensorflow) MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:include hectoresteban$ ls -l /usr/local/include/gdb
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  12080 23 ene  2019 jit-reader.h
```

I have already tried the overwrite and it was because of the overwrite that I messed it up in the first place.

Comment: "First of all, I do not know where gdb 9.1_1 is and how to link it" - Did you try what the helpful error message suggested "`brew link gdb`"?

Comment: sorry I did before but forgot to add the result. Because of the forcing overwriting I got into the problem I am right now

Comment: Did you try `brew link --overwrite gdb` again?

Comment: Yes. I attached the result of that as well

Comment: What is the result of `ls -l /usr/local/include/gdb`?

Comment: (tensorflow) MacBook-Pro-de-Hector-2:include hectoresteban$ ls -l /usr/local/include/gdb
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  12080 23 ene  2019 jit-reader.h